# How to remove chat-head android

Tags: java, android, android-facebook

i learn about android chat-head, i see many of example of it,but i not got answers of how to remove chat head using any event,i want to create chat-head like Facebook-messenger, many of example of floating-window useful to me to create that,but any one please help me to how to remove chat-head, for example in Facebook-messenger we put chat-head in bottom ,one cross automatic open in bottom through that we can remove chat-head.

[image]

Comment: Nirav please provide the solution for the question

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to simply call

```
windowManager.removeView(yourView);
```

to remove whatever view has been added as a ChatHead. For the close button you need to override the onTouch behaviour. Although I don't have any ready sample for this but I would suggest you to make a close button on your Chathead . When the user clicks on the close button you can remove  the view from window manager

Comment: some where i got solutions but when i try to call it when my new activity start at that time i got error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager**

Comment: You maybe calling it multiple times

Comment: Are you sure that your view was added before you called removeView()

Comment: its possible to close view from the another activity ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59174/discussion-between-ajit-pratap-singh-and-nirav-mehta).